# C# Regex Expression retrieving Hierarchial string

Tags: c#, regex

How can I parse the below string using regex expression in C# and return the contents in a match and match groups collection? The start tag is [[ and ]]. Anyone can help?

```
[[Parent1 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]],[[Child 3]]]] [[Parent2 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]]]]
```

Looking for output as below.

```
item: Parent1
Children: [Child1, Child2, Child3]
item: Parent2
Children: [Child1, Child2]
```

Comment: you could get like this `[[Child 1]],[[Child 2]],[[Child 3]]` not like `[Child1, Child2, Child3]`

Comment: Yeah. that would be fine. But how? Thanks.

Comment: You must escape the brackets with \

Comment: Are the parents literally going to becalled `Parent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<=^|]\s)\[\[(\S+)|(\[\[(?!Parent).*?\]\])(?=]]\s|]]$)
```

Group index 1 contains the parent part and group index2 contains the child part.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/23)

```
String input = @"[[Parent1 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]],[[Child 3]]]] [[Parent2 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]]]]";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=^|]\s)\[\[(?<item>\S+)|(?<children>\[\[(?!Parent).*?\]\])(?=]]\s|]]$)");

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Pk9uhA)

Answer (score 0):

What about `((\[\[Parent\d\]\])(\[\[Child \d\]\])+\]\])+`

Not tested actually

Answer (score 0):

```
(?'parent'Parent\d )|(?!^)\G(?:\[\[(?'child'.*?)]]),?
```

In groups 'parent' all parent éléments and in group 'child' all childs éléments

```
  using System;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
  public class Test
    {
    public static void Main()
    {
     String input = @"[[Parent1 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]],[[Child 3]]]] [[Parent2 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]]]]";
     Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<parent>Parent\d )|(?!^)\G(?:\[\[(?<child>.*?)]]),?");
     foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
    {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["parent"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["child"].Value);
    }
    }
    }
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/UbytII)

Answer (score 0):

How about converting it to something more well understood - JSON:

```
string ConvertToJson(string input)
{
    var elements = input
        // replace all square brackets with quotes
        .Replace("[[", "\"").Replace("]]", "\"") 
        // fix double quotes
        .Replace("\"\"", "\"")
        // split on all space-quote combos
        .Split(new[] { " \"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        // make sure all elements start and end with a quote
        .Select(x => "\"" + x.Trim('"') + "\"")
        // make all odd elements the parent item and all even the children collection
        .Select((x, i) => (i % 2 == 0) 
            ? ("{\"item\":" + x) 
            : ",\"children\":[" + x + "]},");

    // turn back into string, remove unneeded comma at end and wrap in an array
    return "[" + String.Concat(elements).Trim(',') + "]";
}
```

Input:

```
[[Parent1 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]],[[Child 3]]]] [[Parent2 [[Child 1]],[[Child 2]]]]
```

Output:

```
[{"item":"Parent1","children":["Child 1","Child 2","Child 3"]},{"item":"Parent2","children":["Child 1","Child 2"]}]
```

You can then use JSON.NET or whatever to play with it as you will.

**You'll also note that this solution has no requirement on the parents being called `Parent` as other solutions here do. And as a bonus, no Regex in sight...**

---

For completeness here's an example using JSON.NET to deserialize it:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("item: {0}", item.item);
    Console.WriteLine("Children: [{0}]", String.Join(", ", item.children));
}
```

which outputs

> item: Parent1
>   Children: [Child 1, Child 2, Child 3]
>   item: Parent2
>   Children: [Child 1, Child 2]